# How can I train my cat to keep her claws retracted while on my lap

Tags: cats, training

I have a black and white cat who likes to occasionally come and sit on my lap. Unfortunately when she gets very comfortable she flexes her claws in and out (kneading) which is not exactly comfortable for me.

With other cats (including other people's) when they do this I just put them off my lap until they figure it out. The problem here is that while these other cats really wanted to be held Molly will just wander off and do something else and does not try to get back up. Thus the cycle of figuring out the trigger that had her removed is not present.

Short of clipping her claws (which I'd rather not) is there some other way that I can I train her to keep her claws to herself?

Comment: By "clipping her claws" do you mean trimming nails or [declawing?](http://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/485)

Comment: This isn't training her to stop, but I just kept a towel or blanket handy with my "kneady" cat to protect the skin without destroying the moment.