# Clipping he's claws

Tags: cats

I have a 6 month old kitten. He is mostly a indoor cat. But sometimes I would let him go out into my fenced in back yard. I have a 6' wooden fence all around. He loves to go out there and play. But he has started to climb the fence and go over into the next yards. So I was wondering if I clipped he's claws will that stop his climbing.

Comment: I am not sure if you mean clipping nails or declawing.  In either case we have the answer [here](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/18171/is-it-necessary-to-keep-a-cats-nails-trimmed) or [here](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/485/when-is-declawing-a-viable-option-for-cats)